# badge should be set before opening the app in IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova-plugins

When notification received on IOS device at that time the badge should be changed and Badge should be set before opening the app.

I check this onNotificationOpen() method. But when I tap on notification then it calls.

I use `cordova-plugin-firebase`.
Here is the link https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase

But is there a method that calls when the notification received on IOS device?

```
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    if (typeof FirebasePlugin != 'undefined') {
      window.FirebasePlugin.subscribe("notficationsubscribe");

      // Below method calls when i tap on notifcation and sets the badge number             
      window.FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen(function(data) {
          window.FirebasePlugin.setBadgeNumber(4);
      }
    }
  }
```

Above FirebasePlugin.onNotificationOpen() method calls when I tap on notification and sets the badge number, but I want to set the badge when notification received.

Anyone have ideas? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually i set a logic for it.

**1)** I stored a badgeCounter value to database.

**2)** when i wants to send the notification at that time i retrieve it from database

```
 var badge = badgeCounter // it is an integer value

 var notification = {
    'title': 'Stock available',
    'body': 'Click here to more details...',
    'sound': 'default',
    'badge': badge 
 };
```

**3)** After tap or click on notification, i cleared the badge using below.
   `window.FirebasePlugin.setBadgeNumber(0);`

**4)** And also in database i update the value to '0' (zero).

Thus, i solve it and  it perfectly works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't set this with code, it will set itself based on what your notification contains. You'll have to include `"badge":1` (or whatever number) in the notification payload when you send it from your server (Firebase). I'm not sure how it works with firebase, but take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html) for remote notifications. Notice the "Badge"-key.